# Uanble to set ScreenSaver on Windows Server 2008 R2 Terminal Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, terminal-server, windows

I am unable to set ScreenSaver on windows Server 2008 R2 Terminal Server. It is in Workgroup, The ScreenSaver work fine if we take Console session, but it doesn't work in Remote Desktop Session.

I require because i want to display some policy with ScreenSaver to User. As per my Search i found that we can't set ScreenSaver in Window Server 2008 R2 Terminal Server.

Is there any Workaround.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The default behavior of the NT Kernel is to try and consume bandwidth.  This prevents you from using the screensaver in both the client and server versions.  In addition to the bandwidth required the RDP mechanism is not designed to support active video (without some additional roles/features enabled) and therefore the screensaver, even if enabled, would appear blocky and in a state of constantly buffering.

Regardless, you haven't really quantified your rationale for wanting to do this.  There aren't many real-world reasons to do this outside of VDI, which you are obviously not doing in a workgroup mode.